# Why is my TypeScript object patch function not working with empty patch objects?

Tags: typescript, patch

I have the following generic function written in TypeScript, should apply a patch to an object where the patch is a partial object of the same type:

```js
function applyPatch<T extends object>(obj: T, patch: Readonly<Partial<T>>): T {
  const patched = { ...obj, ...patch };
  console.log(`obj: ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
  console.log(`patch: ${JSON.stringify(patch)}`);
  console.log(`patched: ${JSON.stringify(patched)}`);
  return patched;
}
```

This should be easy enough. I tested the function in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwA6oDYE8AKyoQAWAPACqICmAHlBWACYDOicARgFYXQB8AFG+wBciUgBpEqfEWEAlCsnoJsxPACdYyDGW7cAlMPIBvAFCJEEBIygSphCvUQBeRIcQA6DwPEe3kgoUQAXwBuU3NLOAwKNww4AHNeAAMBYQASQwApAGUAeQA5NytVGDA4mGAsfg5dQMTdULMLMEZI6NiExL9pRHTs-MKoYtLyyq7CGrqG8ObWmPiksfs0zNyCopKyit5F+gn6sNUKKBBVJB3QwONjNExcW15XGHphACJaKxfxenxkV-eob5QZAvILiQyBfZAA) and it definitely works as expected.

I am running that function with cloudflare wrangler pages for local development at the time, and it seems to work for almost all cases, except for the case where the patch object is an empty object `{}`.

I have tried everything for quite some time now, but I cannot possible understand how this output happened:

```
obj: {"id":"test","data":"testdata"}
patch: {}
patched: {"id":"test"}
```

What is going on here? How is it possible that the `data` property just disappeared?

I was definitely expecting the `data` property to be set when running this.

Comment: Do you need to tag this with whatever "cloudflare wrangler pages" is? Right now this doesn't seem to be a [mre]; I mean, I can't reproduce it in my IDEs. Could you give some kind of procedure to reproduce, or tag it with whatever tags would bring the right experts here?  If it turns out to be something where your environment is relevant, then we need people who understand that environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where your `patch` object comes from or how it's created, but I see only one way how this could happen, ie if your `patch` is not `{}` but `{ testdata: undefined }`. `JSON.stringify` will not serialize the `undefined` property, so it seems it vanished

```js
let obj = {"id": "foo", "testdata": "bar" }
let patch = { "testdata": undefined }
let patched = {...obj, ...patch}

console.log("obj", obj);
console.log("obj", JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log("patch", patch);
console.log("patch", JSON.stringify(patch));
console.log("patched", patched);
console.log("patched", JSON.stringify(patched));
```

Depending on what you expect to happen in such a case, you could for instance remove the `undefined` values from the `patch` object.

```js
let obj = {"id": "foo", "testdata": "bar" }
let patch = { "testdata": undefined }

for (let k in patch) {
  if (patch[k] === undefined) delete patch[k];
}

let patched = {...obj, ...patch}

console.log("obj", obj);
console.log("obj", JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log("patch", patch);
console.log("patch", JSON.stringify(patch));
console.log("patched", patched);
console.log("patched", JSON.stringify(patched));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to be the error. Its really intuitive for me that an undefined field value is not equal to a missing field value. I thought thats what null should be used for.

Answer (score -1):

Nested! You need deep merging:

```
import merge from "lodash.merge";

function applyPatch<T extends object>(obj: T, patch: Readonly<Partial<T>>): T {
  const patched = merge({}, obj, patch);
  console.log(`obj: ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
  console.log(`patch: ${JSON.stringify(patch)}`);
  console.log(`patched: ${JSON.stringify(patched)}`);
  return patched;
}
```

Comment: While `lodash.merge` may solve the problem, your explanation is wrong. It has nothing to do with nested structures or deep merging. The only possibility, that such a result could happen is, if `patch = { testdata: undefined}`. `lodash.merge` may handle this `undefined` value differently from `{...patch}` though ...